# Ionic iOS: Navigating our of native view causes white space

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

**Hello all!**

The application that we are using uses a native plugin for viewing and manipulating PDFs and is launched from within the Cordova WebView.

Everything is as usual until a certain series rotations are performed.

Opening the PDF in portrait (launching the native view over the WebView), rotating the screen to landscape and then navigating out the the native view causes the white section (see images below).

**Notes**

- The interesting part of this bug is that it does not happen on any of the iOS simulators or Android, but is present in both iOS 8 & 9 devices.
- I cannot find them white space in the DOM by using the Safari web inspector (because unlike chrome, you cannot click to inspect certain sections of the document).
- There is a scroll bar, and the height of the white space is EXACTLY the same size as the width of the side bar.

Any suggestions or recommendations on solving this issue would be fantastic and greatly appreciated!

---

**Steps**

1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7aix4bvkqsl2m2/IMG_0183.jpg?dl=0
2. Exit PDF
3. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ugnvdl5a0z0ywg/IMG_0185.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

this is Peter from PSPDFKit - the PDF framework you're using here.

I doubt it's us that causes this issue but it seems that the parent view doesn't correctly update on rotation. Apple changed a few callbacks on iOS 9 and older code that relies on `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is no longer called when not on screen. I don't have much experience with Ionic but it's possible that they simply are not aware of this change or that you're using an older version. We've seen a similar bug in Cordova a while ago.